# Doesn't storing salt in the hash by Bcrypt make it less secure?

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I am currently working in node and noticed that bcrypt puts the salt in the initial portion of the hash

```
password
:
"$2a$04$kpj4oCA/b85xWAIL3n4l9uPMA2Ku4VR90oT3iE9IZVvREvmmJCZem"

salt
:
"$2a$04$kpj4oCA/b85xWAIL3n4l9u"
```

Is doing this safe. I mean the purpose of hashing and salting is to stop the developers from inserting plain passwords in the database. So if someone gets into my database now they know my salt and then its just the matter of brute forcing all the passwords until i get the rest of the hash. Why is salting necessary then? I could just store the hash only without salting

Answer (score 1):

The salt is usually saved as plain text, the logic behind the random salt is so every hash is different with the same password + random salt you get a more random hash and not the same hash with the same password. To counter rainbow table reverse hashing etc.

Without a random salt the password "test" would always generate the same hash when using the same hashing algorithm, so knowing the plain salt can not be used to reverse the password in that manner.

That's just my short explanation, if you want to read more about salt and hashing I'm sure there is plenty of info on that topic available somewhere.